# Secure Native App OAuth2 Code Flow + PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

I'm studying the forms to protect a native app login and found it: https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce.

Well, I understand that is unsecure use code flow in native app because user can decompile the app and get client secret. With client secret user can call authorization server any time thought postman, for example.

I don't see how adding PKCE (code verifier and code challenge) can be better. Think as a attacker, I can generate a PKCE pair and simulate the same thing as App, because I have client secret, for me PKCE just give more work to attacker.

I can create a code challenge and a code verifier randomly , send code challenge to authorization server and use my code verifier to get request token.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the main protection is that authorization responses are only returned on a URL that you own. For a web UI this will be a domain based url such as this:

- https://mycompany.com/myapp

It is possible though difficult to use claimed https schemes for a mobile app, though almost no-one uses it due to the lack of vendor / browser support.

For custom URL schemes the hope is that the environment (App / Play store approval) prevents a malicious third party from registering a URL like this without proof at registration time that they are from 'my company':

- com.mycompany.myapp:/callback

You are right that there is a potential gap here, though I have not heard of any real world exploits.

Comment: Hmm .. Is not dangerous install some reverse proxy in my Android Phone and intercept all requests to "com.mycompany.myapp:/callback" ? With this I can do anythin and "mock" the real app.

Comment: True - recent trends for [financial grade apps](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-1-ID2.html#native-apps) - see section 7.5 - are therefore recommending claimed https schemes - though I've not figured out how to implement that yet - will update my [mobile samples](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) when I get some time - that would solve your problem.

Comment: Good, I will read your https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/. I don't get what means "claimed https schemes", I think i need read more about it.

Comment: Gary I found a good explanation for PKCE purpose, see here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175465/what-is-pkce-actually-protecting&ved=2ahUKEwi53rCQ5YDoAhVNIbkGHfkhAJsQjjgwBnoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0apuQ6UN0D_PgeWt-VkzLe